# Unable to perform javascript functions on Rails mobile site

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, ruby-on-rails, mobile

I have a existing website in rails 2.3.8 which i want to develop for mobile phones(andriod,iphone), something like facebook's mobile site.

I found that creating the view pages with extension .mobile.erb will do the job. 
But the problem is i am unable to call existing javascript functions on mobile site which i used for the main site.

I want to know if it is possible to call js or is there any alternative way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can use javascript on you mobile web pages. For iOS and Android. For other mobile i don't know.

Doc for safari ios : http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/safari/index.action

Answer (score 0):

For iPhone you can use the iUI framework http://code.google.com/p/iui/ which consists of a JavaScript library, and CSS similar to that of native iOS apps.